# Call method after async task is finished

Tags: android, asynchronous, task

So I have an Async Task that makes some operation in doInBackground and then in onPostExecute I'm adding variables to sharedpreferences after finishing I want use some of this values but they are not updated. I need to 'update' my activity like change orientation or something. It seems that Async task is executed at the end even there is some code after.

In my acitivity:

```
myAsyncTask.execute(location1);
System.out.println("Current_time: " + sharedPreferences.getString("CURRENT_TIME", ""));
```

In ASyncTask onPostExecute:

```
editor.putString("CURRENT_TIME", channel.getItem().getCondition().getDate());
Log.i("SetValues", "now");
editor.apply();
```

And the result is:

```
I/System.out: Current_time: Mon, 30 Apr 2018 07:00 PM YEKT
I/SetValues: now
```

And what I want is to finish Async task and then do rest, so first 'SetValues' and then print.

Comment: Asynchronous call . This is the way it behave . A new thread starts when you call `execute()` . So you need to do all your work in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the printing of current time to `onPostExecute` if you want to see the end time of the task. 
Right now it is printing the **start time** of the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Async task runs separately from ui thread.so after executing this the ui doesn’t wait for finishing this task and continue to execute other lines.In async task there’s some over ride method those are called on different event.One of them is onPostExecute which is called when the task of async task is finished mean the doin background method finished.So if you want to do something after one asynctask execution then you have to do this onPost execute method.So do you shared prf works on onPostExecute method.